# Retriving data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables with below description.

- table 1: customer, columns : customer_id, source
- table 2: source, columns: source, rank

one customer would have many sources, each source has a particular rank in the rank table, i need to fetch the data in such a way that for each individual customer which ever has a lowest ranked source i need to fetch those records.

Here is an example:

customer table data is

```
1 abc
2 efg
3 abc
1 efg
1 hij
2 hij
```

source table data is

```
abc 2
hij 1
efg 3
```

the result set should be:

```
1 hij
2 hij
3 abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use either of the two queries below to satisfy your requirement.

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT c.customer_id, 
       c.source 
FROM   customer c 
       INNER JOIN source s 
               ON c.source = s.source 
WHERE  s.rank = (SELECT Min(s1.rank) 
                 FROM   source s1 inner join customer c1 on s1.source = c1.source
                 WHERE  c1.customer_id = c.customer_id)
```

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT x.customer_id ,
       c1.source
FROM
  (SELECT c.customer_id ,
          MIN(s.rank) AS MinRank
   FROM customer c
   INNER JOIN SOURCE s ON c.source = s.source
   GROUP BY c.customer_id) x
INNER JOIN customer c1 ON x.customer_id = c1.customer_id
INNER JOIN SOURCE s1 ON s1.source = c1.source
AND s1.rank = x.MinRank;
```

**UPDATE 1**

This update is in response to your comment for 3 tables rather than 2 tables. The query below extends **Query 1** when your schema is spread across 3 tables.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, 
       s.source_name 
FROM   customer c 
       INNER JOIN source s 
               ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id 
       INNER JOIN rank r 
               ON s.source_name = r.source_name 
WHERE  r.rank = (SELECT Min(r1.rank) 
                 FROM   customer c1 
                        INNER JOIN  source s1
                                ON s1.cust_id = c1.cust_id 
                        INNER JOIN rank r1 
                                ON r1.source_name = s.source_name 
                 WHERE  c1.cust_id = c.cust_id);
```

Comment: What if we have 3 different tables spread across.. customer, source, rank : columns of customer: cust_id, name , source : source_name, cust_id , rank: source_name, rank ..? now i need to write query to extract the same cust_id, min(rank).

Comment: That would not be a problem. I will post in about an hour's time.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle:

```
select d.customer_id, d.source
from (
    select
        c.customer_id,
        s.source,
        row_number() over (partition by c.customer_id order by s.rank asc) as rn
    from customer c
        join source s
            on c.source = s.source
) d
where d.rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way. Try this -

```
select c.cid,c.sourceid,min(s.rankid)
from customer c inner join sourc s 
on (c.sourceid=s.sourceid) 
group by c.cid order by c.cid asc
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a306da/5)

Comment: Definitely won't work in Oracle, `c.sourceid` missing in `group by`. Is it standart SQL or some mysql dialect?

Comment: Standard sql, works perfectly in mysql, sql server. I haven't checked in Oracle.

Comment: On the SQLFiddle you provided MS SQL Server says "Column 'customer.sourceid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: This is wrong. It works in MySQL only because MySQL is clever about functional dependencies. It works in SQLite. In all other SQL implementations, and in the SQL standard, it's an error.

Comment: Thanks for this information Bill. I will add a comment in answer that says Only for mysql. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.customer_id,b.source
from
(select c.customer_id,min(s.rank) as rank
from customer c 
inner join source s 
on c.source=s.source 
group by c.customer_id) as a
inner join source b
on a.rank = b.rank
```